# Numpy Logarithm works for boolean Pandas Series but not for boolean column in Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Given a dataframe `df`:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1., -2.5, True], [2.5, -1., False]])
>>> df
     0    1      2
0  1.0 -2.5   True
1  2.5 -1.0  False
>>> df.dtypes
0    float64
1    float64
2       bool
dtype: object
```

Taking the logarithm of the first two columns (a Pandas Dataframe) runs without errors.

```
>>> np.log(df.iloc[:,:2])
          0   1
0  0.000000 NaN
1  0.916291 NaN
```

I know that it does not make sense to take the logarithm of a boolean, but if I try to take the logarithm of the three columns (a Pandas Dataframe), I get the following error:

```
>>> np.log(df)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'log'
```

However, if I try take the logarithm only of the third column, i.e., a Pandas Series, it runs without errors.

```
>>> np.log(df.iloc[:,2])
__main__:1: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in log
0    0.000000
1        -inf
Name: 2, dtype: float16
```

Just for the sake of curiosity: why there are these two different behaviors when applying `numpy.log` in a Pandas boolean Series or in a Pandas Dataframe with a boolean column?

Comment: It seems related to the fact that `df.values` yields an array of dtype `object`. Some numpy functions cannot deal with it even if the individual items are of numeric types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
In [15]: np.log(df.astype(float))
...
skipped warnings
...
Out[15]:
          0   1         2
0  0.000000 NaN  0.000000
1  0.916291 NaN      -inf
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transform it all data to float in numpy. However there are some values that are not going to have a result.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1., -2.5, True], [2.5, -1., False]])
np.log(np.array(df,dtype=np.float64))
#result
array([[ 0.        ,         nan,  0.        ],
       [ 0.91629073,         nan,        -inf]])
```

Comment: Thanks @silgon, but I'm wondering why the log works for the Series but not for the column.

Comment: I see what you mean. My only guess it's that everything is parsed to be computed by numpy, and since in your dataframe you have various types of variables (float and boolean), it throws you the error.